uniqueness of equivalence of group extension / lifting action on group to extension
Let $E$ be a central extension of a group $G$ by $A$, that is, we have an exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
 1 \to A \xrightarrow{\iota} E \xrightarrow{\pi} G \to 1
\end{equation*}
and $A$ is contained in the center $Z(E)$ of $E$. An automorphism of such an extension is a ladder
\begin{equation*}\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
 1 @>>> A @>{\iota}>> E @>{\pi}>> G @>>> 1 \\
 @. @| @V\varphi VV @| @. \\
 1 @>>> A @>{\iota}>> E @>{\pi}>> G @>>> 1.
\end{CD}\end{equation*}
If the extension splits, $\varphi$ must be the identity because $E$ is then generated by the respective images of $A$ and $G$ in $E$. However, is this also true in general?
Concretely, I am considering a group $H$ acting on the left of $G$, whose induced action on $H^2(G, A)$ fixes the class associated to the central extension. For every $h\in H$, we get a ladder
\begin{equation*}\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
 1 @>>> A @>{\iota}>> E\times_G G @>>> G @>>> 1 \\
 @. @| @Vh^*VV @VhVV @. \\
 1 @>>> A @>{\iota}>> E @>{\pi}>> G @>>> 1.
\end{CD}\end{equation*}
and we know that the upper row is equivalent to our original extension. Note that
\begin{equation}
 E \times_G G = \{(\epsilon, g) \in E\times G \mid \pi(\epsilon) = h.g\}
\end{equation}
for a fixed $h\in H$.
If we could identify a canonical equivalence, we would obtain a right action of $H$ on $E$; this is what I would be interested to construct.

Don't you have a canonical map $E \to E \times_G G$ ?

@AAAL I don't see it, I can only come up with $E \to E \times G, \epsilon \mapsto (\epsilon, 1)$, whose image does not restrict to $E\times_G G$ as it is clear from the last sentence which I added to the second paragraph.

you have $e \mapsto (e, \pi(e))$

@AAAL this isn't well-defined either because $\pi(e) \neq h.\pi(e)$. We can try alternatively $e \mapsto (e, h^{-1}.\pi(e))$, but that is not an equivalence of extensions.

Oh yes, sorry !

I remembered a classical counterexample. Consider the exact sequence $$ 1 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/4 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 1 .$$ Then $\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{Z}/4}$ and $-\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{Z}/4}$ are both automorphisms of the exact sequence.
